# SQL Query populate results based on specific values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to pull a report to highlights which users are in my system and their access level as well as group membership.

Users are in a table called **users** /

Groups are in a table called **groups**/ groups are linked to the user using the employee code of the user

Roles are in a table called **roles** / roles are linked to the users using the pkey of the user

A user can be member of several groups and have several roles and I am aiming to have a SQL query returning this in a table where my columns will be my groups and roles and the rows will be the users. Ideally I want to poulate the column witha  X when a user is member of a group or role is assigned

So far I have worked on statements with UNION and several joints but I am unable to put that in a table and poulate with a x when the user is part of a group or has a role assigned.

Any assitance is much appreciated!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? Please also add the table definitions as `create table` statements including some sample data and the expected output based on that data (ideally create a little http://sqlfiddle.com)

Comment: Dynamically defining columns is MUCH easier in a app/reporting layer than in SQL.  Some SQL systems have a "pivot" function but they usually aren't dynamic (you have to specify the columns) unless you resort to dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the information you gave, i think what you want to do is the next:

```
select u.idUser, u.username, 
STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + convert(varchar,g.groupname)
        from groups g
        where g.IdUser = u.iduser 
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE   
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')   
        ,1,1,'') as rutas,
STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + convert(varchar,r.rolename)
        from Roles r
        where r.IdUser = u.iduser 
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE   
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')   
        ,1,1,'') as rutas,
from users u 
where u.idUser = 4882
```

Only modify the query with the names of your table rows, or edit your question and gave this data to give you the exact answer.